# Как правильно прописывать математические действия в коде?

Tags: python, sqlite3

Вопрос по своей сути простой, но я хочу узнать самый быстрый и надежный способ!
Имеется такой фрагмент кода:

```
    async with state.proxy() as data:
        try:
            for id_inbd in cur.execute(f"SELECT name FROM wins WHERE name = '{tuple(data.values())[1]}'").fetchone():
                gw = cur.execute(f"SELECT game,win FROM wins WHERE name = '{id_inbd}'").fetchone()
                gw_all = cur.execute(f"SELECT game,win FROM wins_all WHERE name = '{id_inbd}'").fetchone()
                game1 = int(tuple(data.values())[2]) + int(gw[0])
                win1 = int(tuple(data.values())[3]) + int(gw[1])
                game_all = int(tuple(data.values())[2]) + int(gw_all[0])
                win_all = int(tuple(data.values())[3]) + int(gw_all[1])
                cur.execute(f'UPDATE wins SET game = ?, win = ? WHERE name = ?', (game1, win1, id_inbd,))
                cur.execute(f'UPDATE wins_all SET game = ?, win = ? WHERE name = ?', (game_all, win_all, id_inbd,))
                base.commit()
        except TypeError:
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO wins VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(data.values()))
            cur.execute('INSERT INTO wins_all VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)', tuple(data.values()))
            base.commit()
```

Математические действия закрепляются переменной, но мне кажется, что такой вариант кода неправильный!
Имеется ли смысл хранить вычисления в переменных, или лучше производить расчеты непосредственно в аргументах записи в бд?
Жду ваше мнение и критику, касательно этого кода.

Comment: А это зависит от того, может ли у вас одновременно какой нибудь другой процесс так же производить запись в БД. В общем случае, если считать что БД многопользовательская, ваш подход опасен, потому как между тем как вы сделали select и делаете update другой процесс уже мог что то изменить в этих записях, и вы не учтете тех изменений.  Кроме того вообще весь этот код можно заменить двумя запросами, которые и вставят записи, если их нет, или изменят, если есть (Ведь если БД сказала что записи нет, кто то за это время мог ее вставить !). https://www.sqlite.org/lang_UPSERT.html

Comment: Это разве нормально, что в качестве примера показан вариант с sql иньекцией? Можно как то без нее использовать upsert?

Comment: Где вы там инъекцию увидели ? Это же описание языка sql, а значит оно написано с предположением, что запросы пишутся от руки в коносоле какой нибудь. Это просто синтаксис языка. А все плейсхоледры для передачи параметров уже касаются конкретного языка из которого вы работаете и  могут отличаться в разных языках. Так что вопросики сами расставите прекрасно

Comment: у вас в коде кстати то де хватает мест где надо бы заменить переменные, подставленные в текст на вопросы, в первых трех запросах например